# Proof clarification of Laplace transform heaviside stepfunction and timeshifted function

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, laplace-transform, differential

I am having trouble with the derivation of the Laplace transform of the heaviside step function and a time-shifted function.

$$u_c(t) = \Big \lbrace_{1, \; t \geq c}^{0, \;t \leq c}$$

**Deriving:**
$$ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  \int _{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} u_c(t)f(t-c) dt$$

Since the step function is 0 until t = c, the integral bounds change and the function is changed to 1:
$$ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  \int _{c}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t-c) dt$$

Change of variable:
$$ \tau = t -c; \; d \tau = dt$$

The integral bounds change as well, at t=c:

$$ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  \int _{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(\tau + c)} f(\tau) d \tau$$
$$ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  \int _{0}^{\infty} e^{-s\tau -sc} f(\tau) d \tau$$
$$\boxed{ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  e^{-sc} \underbrace{\int _{0}^{\infty} e^{-s\tau} f(\tau) d \tau}_{= L \lbrace f(\tau) \rbrace} = e^{-sc}F(s) }$$

Now approaching it again, but substituting back in for tau:
$$ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  e^{-sc} \underbrace{\int _{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(t-c)} f(t-c) d t}_{= L \lbrace f(t-c) \rbrace}$$

What seems confusing to me is by substituting back in t for tau, it seems as if you need to do the Laplace transform on the timeshifted function as opposed to the non-timeshifted function.

Without substitution:
$$L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace = e^{-sc} L \lbrace f(t) \rbrace$$

With substitution:
$$L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace = e^{-sc} L \lbrace f(t-c) \rbrace$$

Can someone explain where I have made the error that makes these two approaches diverge?

**EDIT**:
Answering in case someone stumbles on this in the future. As eyeballfrog said, if the integral is evaluated from c to infinity, then the two approaches are equivalent.

$$\boxed{ L \lbrace u_c(t)f(t-c) \rbrace =  e^{-sc} \underbrace{\int _{c}^{\infty} e^{-s(t-c)} f(t-c) d t}_{= L \lbrace f(t-c) \rbrace} }$$

With an example
$$u_c(t) = \Big \lbrace_{1, \; t \geq 1}^{0, \;t \leq 1}$$

$$f(t) = t - (t-1)u_c$$

$$L \lbrace f(t) \rbrace = L \lbrace t \rbrace + L \lbrace u_c(t-1) \rbrace$$

$$L \lbrace t \rbrace = \frac{1}{s^2}$$
$$L \lbrace u_c (t-1) \rbrace = \int _{1}^{\infty} e^{-s(t-1)}(t-1) \; dt = \frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}$$

Comment: To back this up with an example:

$$f(t) = \Big \lbrace_{0, \; t \geq 1}^{t, \;t \leq 1}$$

Creating the single line function with the step function:

$$u_c(t) = \Big \lbrace_{1, \; t \geq 1}^{0, \;t \leq 1}$$

$$f(t) = t - (t-1)u_c$$

Evaluating the Laplace transform of this gives:
$$L \lbrace f(t) \rbrace = L \lbrace t \rbrace + L \lbrace u_c(t-1) \rbrace$$

$$L \lbrace t \rbrace = \frac{1}{s^2}$$
$$L \lbrace u_c\underbrace{(t-1)}_{g(t)} \rbrace = e^{-s}L \lbrace g(t) = t \rbrace = \frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}$$

$$L \lbrace f(t) \rbrace = \frac{1}{s^2} - \frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}$$

Comment: Approaching from a different way by expanding f(t):
$$f(t) = t - (t-1)u_c = t - u_ct + u_c$$
$$L \lbrace f(t) \rbrace = L \lbrace t \rbrace - L \lbrace u_ct \rbrace + L \lbrace u_c \rbrace$$
$$L \lbrace t \rbrace = \frac{1}{s^2}$$

Since no timeshift, c = 0
$$L \lbrace u_ct \rbrace = e^{-sc} L \lbrace t \rbrace = \frac{1}{s^2}$$

$$L \lbrace u_c \rbrace = \frac{e^{-sc}}{s}$$

$$ \boxed{L \lbrace f(t) \rbrace = \frac{1}{s^2} - \frac{1}{s^2} + \frac{e^{-sc}}{s}} $$

Comment: When you sub back in for $\tau$, you have to change the limits of integration back to $(c, \infty)$.